# unable to access context_object_name in templates

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to iterate over my context object in templates but it's not working. Here's what I have:

views.py:

```
class PortfolioStockListView(ListView):
     model = StockPortfolio
     template_name = 'home.html'
     context_object_name = 'stock_portfolio'
```

models.py:

```
class StockPortfolio(models.Model):
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    stock_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('stocks', StocksPageView.as_view(), name='stocks'),
]
```

In my template home.html:

```
{% for item in stock_portfolio %}
    <li>{{ item.stock_symbol }}</li>
    <li>{{ item.stock_qty }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't seem to find what the issue is here. In my template, the items aren't displayed.

Comment: Your `PortfolioStockListView` is nowhere in your `urls`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I've tried adding `path('', PortfolioStockListView.as_view(), name='home') -- still not showing up

Comment: Did you append it to the end of the urls? Because the `''` pattern of the `HomePageView` will match all requests.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Got it, this fixed it! Thank you so much!